# Cannot display one user data in admin page

Tags: php, sql, database

This is an admin page, should display all data for the selected user
I am trying to display data for one user only, but get an empty page:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['user']))
     {
        $user = $_POST['user'];

        //if username has been selected
        if($user == "none") 
           {
              echo '<div class="error"><p>No user has been selected</p></div>';
              echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="1; url=adminPanel.php">';
            }
            else
            {

            //form query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE user =  '$user'";

        //Execute query
        $query_result = mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<table>';
        while($user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
                {

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$user_data['user'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$user_data['email'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$user_data['added'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$user_data['admin'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$user_data['type'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                }
        echo '</table>';        
            }
}
?>
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Clean up SQL injection use PDO prepare statement. http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Don't use mysql. Use PDO or mysqli instead. Also, how are you sending the "user" var through post? Are you using a form? Try var_dump($_POST); and see if it's set indeed.

Comment: Lol do you know that you redirect to different page in a second ?

Comment: If the page is completely blank with no errors, then that if statement is resolving to true. To test, you can include a var_dump on your $_POST variable. You can also echo mysql_num_rows to then make sure you're getting data from your db. But most importantly, I have to agree with the previous comment. This is HIGHLY HIGHLY unsafe code for an admin page. You are running a query on an unsanitized $_POST var without any validation. This would take a hacker about two seconds to delete your entire table!

Comment: If it's a blank white page it's probably a 500 internal server error. Check your error log. @Ryan though correct about it being unsafe code, it's actually not possible to delete the table through this SQL Injection because `mysql_query()` does not support multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

you should try first:
   echo "ROW COUNT: ".mysql_num_rows($query);
or you could throw a var_dump($user_data);

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this. As the others said, it would be much better to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but at least with `mysql_real_escape_string()` you're safer than you were inputting the data directly into the query.

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST['user']) || $_POST['user'] == 'none') {
        exit('No user was selected set.');
    }

    $user = (string) mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

    $sql = "
        SELECT user, email, added, admin, type
        FROM User
        WHERE user = '%s'";
    $query_string = sprintf($sql, $user);

    $result = mysql_query($query_string);

    if (empty($result)) {
        exit('Failed to retrieve user data.');
    }

    echo '
        <table>';
    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>', $user['user'], '</td>
                <td>', $user['email'], '</td>
                <td>', $user['added'], '</td>
                <td>', $user['admin'], '</td>
                <td>', $user['type'], '</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    echo '
        </table>';
```